# How to convert two character strings to the same encoding? Using R

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, character, non-ascii-characters

I have two identical characters strings:

- a = DASYATIS BREVICAUDATA
- b = DASYATIS BREVICAUDATA

However they are coming up as non identical where a == b is coming up as FALSE. I have figured out now that they have different encodings:

- detect_str_enc(a)

> [1] "ASCII"

- detect_str_enc(b)

> [1] "MAC-CENTRALEUROPE"

In addition when i run a [function](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/279354_f552c4c41852439f910ad620763960b6.html) i can further see the difference between the two.

- details(a)

> ```
> x                       encoding  bytes chars width
> ```
>
> [1,] "DASYATIS BREVICAUDATA" "unknown" 21    21    21
> raw
> [1,] "44:41:53:59:41:54:49:53:20:42:52:45:56:49:43:41:55:44:41:54:41"

- details(b)

> ```
> x                       encoding  bytes chars width
> ```
>
> [1,] "DASYATIS BREVICAUDATA" "unknown" 22    21    21
> raw
> [1,] "44:41:53:59:41:54:49:53:c2:a0:42:52:45:56:49:43:41:55:44:41:54:41"

How can i convert these both to the same encoding/string format? so that a == b gives me TRUE

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `iconv`?

Comment: I have but i might be using it wrong as i still get a == b as FALSE. I tried a = iconv(a, to = "UTF-8" , sub="byte"); b = iconv(b, to = "UTF-8" , sub="byte")